# How do I create a configurable product with 3 options

Tags: configurable-product, price, attribute-options

I apologise for the vague title, I didn't know exactly what I'm asking so I'll explain and maybe someone else can come up with a better title...or the solution.

I'm trying to create a website that sells labels, each labels has three options to choose from:

1. How many do you want to buy (e.g. 10 pack, 50 pack, 100 pack)
2. What type of label it is (e.g. Removable, Permanent, Transparent)
3. What colour it is

There first two options combine to form a price, where as the colour option has no bearing on prices.

If for example you wanted a 10 standard labels it might be £2, where as if you wanted 10 removable labels it might be £4. The problem is that when you create a configurable product the cost for each upgrade is +something depending on the selected option, not a fixed price for a combination of options.

I also can't create a basic price with one attribute then add the rest on with another, because you have to add on different amounts depending on how many labels you buy.

Not sure if this is making any sense but hopefully somebody gets a rough idea of what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you aren't kitting these 10/50/100 packs together when an order is placed), the simplest option which will work natively is to use two options:

1. `type_qty`
2. `color`

In this approach the `type_qty` attribute would have the following nine options:

- 10 pack Removable
- 50 pack Removable
- 100 pack Removable
- 10 pack Permanent
- 50 pack Permanent
- 100 pack Permanent
- 10 pack Transparent
- 50 pack Transparent
- 100 pack Transparent

Again, this assumes that these are your literal stock items.

If you take this approach you will probably want to use an attribute manager so that you aren't replicating this stuff across all of your label types such as [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-configurable-product-matrix.html) (**note that I have no experience with this extension and am not implying an endorsement**).